# JS and JQuery: Get the new href only after changing it

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have a below anchor as below

```
<a onclick="return getFile('/log/sample.log');" href="/log/sample.log" target="_blank"> sample.log </a>
```

Because at my server, the log directory in href may be not correct. So the function "getFile" would change the href to the correct one after asking the server.

The first click always failed since the link was not correct, then after AJAX process in getFile was finished and the correct href was given, the clicks later on was ok.

The problem is how I forcefully let html wait ever at the first click until the href is changed, then do the query on the server.

Thanks in advance.

I guess my current way could be not in the correct direction by using "onclick" to implement the idea.

Comment: use href="javascript:void(0)" inside a tag then when click a tag,it will call ajax and there you will get correct path.Finally you can set window.open = "your_file_absolute_path";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this

```
$(function() {

//assume you tagged all anchors you want to do this for with class=adjustlink
$('a.adjustlink').click(function(e) {
  var thisAnchor = $(this); //save reference for later use

  //this will either be true (see below) or undefined (falsy)
  if(thisAnchor.data('myapp.linkHasBeenTested')) {
    return;  //continue on
  } 

   // Stop the link from being navigated (the default for this event)
   e.preventDefault();

  //I'm assuming this is fetched as text but could just as well be JSON or anything else
  $.get('/LinkAdjustment/', thisAnchor.attr('href')).done(function(result) {
    thisAnchor.attr('href', result); //set the href
    thisAnchor.data('myapp.linkHasBeenTested', true);
    thisAnchor.trigger('click');
  });
});

});
```

As an interesting side-note. You might be attempting to do something similar to the way REST [is *intended* to be done](http://timelessrepo.com/haters-gonna-hateoas).  You might consider, first fetching a resource that will tell you up-front what the correct links are.

Comment: The whole idea is so great. Only one issue is about "trigger('click')". It didn't work. I tried "window.open", there was no any action either.

Comment: @Yang - the only reason I can think of why that wouldn't work is if your pop-up blocker stopped it (all modern browsers come with built in ones). Check the area of your browser where it would show this. Here is a working example of this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/gMN5X/1/

Comment: You are right. "window.open" is working now, not for "trigger". For me, it's enough. I'm still wondering why "trigger" is still not working. I'll check it more. Thanks

Comment: @Yang - I am pretty sure that is because of a pop-up blocker. The above example which uses 'trigger' works great for me. My understanding of how pop-up blockers work is that if too much time has passed between a user interaction and a window being opened they will block it. No way around it sadly except to make an exception to the pop up blocker rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend setting the href to # initially. And in your getFile, set the href to the correct value and then programatically click the 'a' on success of your ajax

You will need to find the element to do this. It can either be done by setting an id and then using document.getElementById(), or would be easier to do do this using Jquery selectors, and it even has a .click()  you can call after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want persist with this flow make your ajax call synchronous, it will forcibly wait.

But this flow is not suggested, I would have rather updated these hrefs on page load or would have set a default url to my server page, which would then redirect to right log file